# NestJS. ValidationPipe doesn't handle composite objects

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-transformer

It is common for microservices when body is composited from few models/DTOs, for example I receive Foo DTO in my API Gateway and then send it with User object to microservice. In my case @Transform decorator in Foo DTO doesn't work. But it works if body is just Foo.

```
@MessagePattern(FOO)
async foo(@Body() body: { user: User, data: Foo }){
}

export class Foo {
    @Transform(val => BigInt(val.value))
    amount: bigint;
}

app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}));
```

All types User and Foo are defined, so why ValidationPipe passes this transform?

Comment: What's your version of `class-transformer`?

Comment: I use version 0.4.0. So now I need always to create kind of parent object like this: export class ParentReq {
    user: User
    @Type(() => Foo)
    body: Foo
} it is boring, but what to do :)